# mvn command is not getting executed in cron

Tags: shell, maven, cron

I want to execute maven command (mvn) through a shell script to be executed through cron.

My shell script

```
echo "setting the variables"

export M2_HOME=/Users/<XXXXX>/Downloads/apache-maven-3.5.2
export M2=/Users/<XXXXX>/Downloads/apache-maven-3.5.2/bin
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/<XXXXX>/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/<XXXXX>/Documents/Software/neo-java-web-sdk-3.54.23/tools:/Users/<XXXXX>/Downloads/apache-maven-3.5.2/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Applications/Privileges.app/Contents/Resources:JAVA_HOME/bin


echo "variables set"


{
 /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java -version > /Users/<XXXXX>/git/SimpleTests/org.saurav.simpletests/java.log

} || {

 echo "java command failed"
}


{
 /Users/<XXXXX>/Downloads/apache-maven-3.5.2/bin/mvn -version
} || {

 echo "mvn command failed"
}


echo "Tests Executed"
```

output.log always print

```
setting the variables
variables set
mvn command failed
Tests Executed
```

So, it seems the mvn command execution fails.

Output of java command execution has been redirected to java.log but that prints empty. But it seems the java command execution is happening since the fallback echo statement is not printed here.

Best Regards,

Saurav

Answer (score 0):

It seems the mvn file execution is a protected file execution.

With Mac Mojave the programs accessing the protected files have to be given full disk access

Please check here

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/378553/crontab-operation-not-permitted

https://support.intego.com/hc/en-us/articles/360016683471-Enable-Full-Disk-Access-in-macOS

After i followed the steps mentioned in the link 1, it started working.

Best Regards,
Saurav